# Given $2\text{ °C}$ atmospheric temperature rise, what would be the temperature increase if confined to an oven?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, atmospheric-science, estimation, climate-science

**Consider the 2 °C average global atmospheric temperature rise as discussed by the IPCC.  Assume an oven with an the interior that is a perfect cube having a volume of one cubic meter, empty of everything except air.  What would be the temperature inside the oven if the energy represented by said 2 °C global warming were instead applied to the atmosphere inside the oven?**

---

The problem I'm trying to solve is to make climate change understandable to  friends and family.

We talk about trying to limit global warming to 1.5 °C (if that's even possible any more) or 2 °C.  The problem is that 1.5 °C or even 2 °C doesn't sound so bad on a local level. The temperature goes up and down by that much every day from one sunrise to the next.  Some days it's so cold that a 2 °C rise would be welcome.  What's wrong with a little warming?

What's wrong is that it just seems like a little warming; it's actually a lot of warming spread out over a large area or volume; it's really quite a bit of energy.

To illustrate the amount, suppose we confined it to the volume of an average domestic kitchen oven, say, a cubic meter to make it easy.

That's my question.

For the brief period of time that the oven would continue to exist.

Comment: The trouble with your idea is that the energy from even a very slight increase in global temperature (say 0.01 C) is enough to blow up your oven. So what are you proving?

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin I think what you said goes to my objective of communicating the large amount of energy.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a lot of energy, but since even a small increase in temperature (which would not change anything to the climate) represents already a large amount of energy, it follows that showing that the energy is huge does not prove that the climate is going to change.

Comment: Maybe a better approach is to say that an average 4 degree change is the difference between an ice age and our "usual" climate: https://xkcd.com/1379/

Answer (score 4):

Let's rearrange the definition of heat capacity $C$ as follows:

$$\Delta T =\frac{Q}{mC}$$

where 
$\Delta T$ = the change in the temperature of the mass (in degrees Celsius) 
$Q$ = the heat that causes the rise in temperature (in Joules) 
$m$ = the mass that is having its temperature raised (in kg)

We'll next create a ratio of the change in temperature of the atmosphere (abbreviated $atm$) $\Delta T_{atm}$ to the change in temperature in the oven $\Delta T_{oven}$:

$$\frac{\Delta T_{oven}}{\Delta T_{atm}}=\frac{Q_{oven}}{Q_{atm}}\cdot \frac{m_{atm}C_{atm}}{m_{oven}C_{oven}}$$

Since both the atmosphere and the oven contain air, let's assume that their heat capacities are the same so $C_{atm} = C_{oven}$ and those terms cancel out. The assumption is that the heat is also equal so $Q_{oven} = Q_{atm}$ and those cancel out as well. Rearranging, we are left with:

$$\Delta T_{oven} = \Delta T_{atm} \frac{m_{atm}}{m_{oven}}$$

Increase in temperature of atmosphere $\Delta T_{atm}$ = $2 \text{ °C}$ 
 
[Mass of the atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth#Density_and_mass) $m_{atm}$ = $5.15×10^{18}\ kg $ 
[Mass of air in oven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air) $m_{oven}$ = $1.275\ kg$

Plugging in results in $\Delta T_{oven} = 8.08×10^{18}\text{ °C}$. For reference the [center of the Sun is only](http://coolcosmos.ipac.caltech.edu/ask/7-How-hot-is-the-Sun-) $1.5×10^{6}\text{ °C}$. [More massive stars](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~pogge/Ast162/Unit3/supernova.html) can get up to $1×10^{10}\text{ °C}$. Both are still way colder than your hypothetical oven.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the heat transfer over the entire earth. This simplification uses convection, but you can add conductive and radiative heat transfer if you wanted.

Q=U*A*dT; where Q is the amount of heat, U is the convective heat transfer coefficient (0.5 - 1000 (W/(m^2K) air), A is area, and dT is the temperature change in kelvin.

After finding Q from the surface area of the earth, use this Q value along with the surface area of the oven to find the temperature change. Add that to the ambient value.